# Issue with ngx-pipes filterBy

Tags: angular

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or I just found an error in a ngx-pipe.
So let say I want to filter by id = 1. I'm actually getting ids 1, 11 and 14.

I'm using the example from the documentation, I just added 2 new objects:

```
users = [
    {id: 1, first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', work: { company: 'Foo Tech' }},
    {id: 2, first_name: 'Jane', last_name: 'West', work: { company: 'AAA Solutions' }},
    {id: 3, first_name: 'Bruce', last_name: 'John', work: { company: 'Bar Tech' }},
    {id: 4, first_name: 'William', last_name: 'Cent', work: { company: 'Foo Tech' }, arr: [{name: 'foo'}]},
    {id: 11, first_name: 'William', last_name: 'Cent', work: { company: 'Foo Tech' }, arr: [{name: 'foo'}]},
    {id: 14, first_name: 'William', last_name: 'Cent', work: { company: 'Foo Tech' }, arr: [{name: 'foo'}]}]


<div *ngFor="let user of users | filterBy: ['id']: 1">
 {{user | json}}
</div>
```

Results:

> { "id": 1, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "work": { "company": "Foo Tech" } }
>   { "id": 11, "first_name": "William", "last_name": "Cent", "work": { "company": "Foo Tech" }, "arr": [ { "name": "foo" } ] }
>   { "id": 14, "first_name": "William", "last_name": "Cent", "work": { "company": "Foo Tech" }, "arr": [ { "name": "foo" } ] }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this way

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | filterBy: ['id']: 1: true">
 {{user | json}}
</div>
```

> you need to set strict to true

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kyrucz)

Comment: happy to help 